# How to get information on box account creation using okta api?

Tags: box, okta, boxapiv2, okta-api

okta when configured, automatically creates box accounts for new users added to okta's AD.

Is there any way to get information from box if the account created by okta is successful or not? I am referring only API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the way Okta is configured on your side is that when new users are created in Okta, they are assigned to and created in Box as well (probably using group assignment to Box?)

If that is the case and you want to make sure that users are created in a downstream app Box, you can use Okta's event API to confirm.

Please see this link: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/events.html#application-user-management

The event type (`action.objectType`) you are looking for is: `app.user_management.push_new_user`

You can make following call to get the user created in Box:

```
GET /api/v1/events?filter=published gt "2016-11-17T00:00:00.000Z" and action.objectType eq "app.user_management.push_new_user" and targets[1].displayName eq "<Box_App_Name>"
```

Where `<Box_App_Name>` is the `displayName` of the app under targets as it appears. Before you run the call above, you may need to confirm the `displayName` of Box or alternatively, use the `id` (better than `displayName`) from targets array.